# Smalltalk lazy initialization as method call?

Tags: smalltalk

Having a small problem here with a variable not initializing. Are these equivalent?

```
comments
        ^ comments ifNil: [ comments := OrderedCollection new ]
```

--

```
comments
        ^ comments ifNil: [ self initializeComments ]

initializeComments
    comments := OrderedCollection new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has to return the `comments` variable in the `initializeComments` method, otherwise the `comments` getter method will return `self` for the second variant in case of an uninitialized variable.

I don't want to return anything in `initializeComments` so I used:

```
comments
    ^ comments ifNil: [ self initializeComments. comments ]
```

Or:

```
comments
    comments ifNil: [ self initializeComments ]. 
    ^ comments
```

Thanks Mike!

**PS. For a more detailed explanation see @LeandroCaniglia answer below.**

Comment: I would restrict the access to the variable to a single method: `^ comments ifNil: [ comments := self defaultComments ]`. But that's personal preference.

Comment: If you want to avoid having two returns `^` in the same method you could write it as `comment ifNil: [self initializeComments]. ^comments` In some cases having several returns is ok, but in this one I think it is better to have only one at the end.

Comment: Neither of those are what you want to do. In your first example, you can omit the second `^`, as `comments` will be returned anyway with the caret outside for both nil and non-nil cases. Your second example needs to have the full stop _outside_ the square brackets, not inside (see Leandro's example).

Comment: In the first example where the [ self initializeComments ] returns self as the implementation in the question doesn't explicitly return comments, and the result of this block is what the method finally returns because of ifNil: Try it, you'll see, that ^ comments has to be there. The interesting bit is that having the block [ comments := OrderedCollection new ] which does return comments at the end replaced by [ self initializeComments ] and a initializeComments comments := OrderedCollection new which makes the block return self at the end, and this means the techniques are not equivalent.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter Nevermind, misunderstood the comment. Edited the answer.

Comment: Your first example is still wrong. Just look at the two implementors of `#ifNil:` and you'll get that `UndefinedObject` (i.e. `nil`) returns the value of the block, while everything else returns `self`. Your way, if you call `comments`, you'll end up with the receiver, not the value of the `comments` instance variable. Change it to `^comments ifNil: [self initializeComments. comments]` and it'll work, because the `^` on the outside means that if it's nil (first call), the value of the block will be returned, which is the last statement in it; if not nil, `comments` will return `self`.

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to build on this question.

**Lazy initialization**

This technique makes sense when it saves time and or memory. If the object to be initialized is large, or if initializing it takes too long, it definitely makes sense. Otherwise, it does not.

When deciding this take into account the following considerations:

*Time*: Every access to the ivar will execute a conditional statement (`ifNil:`). So, you have to decide whether it wouldn't be better to initialize the ivar at the beginning, and then just use it without further checking.

*Space*: The object takes some bytes, sure. But the `#initializeFoo` method also takes some bytes because it is a `CompiledMethod`. For instance, if you write

```
initialize
  comments ifNil: [self initializeComments].
  ^comments
```

instead of

```
initialize
  ^comments ifNil: [comments := OrderedCollection new]
```

you will have to compare the space used by a new instance of `OrderedCollection` against the space used by the `CompiledMethod` object defined by:

```
initializeComments
  comments := OrderedCollection new
```

plus the send in the `#comments` accessor method.

Also, the lazy intialization technique prevents any direct reference to the ivar. For instance, if `comments` is lazy, the code will be forced to use `self comments` everywhere, which, BTW, takes additional space because the sender will need a slot in its literal frame for the `#comments` selector. Many people think that ivars should always be accessed via messages anyway, but not having the option to just name the ivar cannot be a good thing either. Moreover, methods that access the ivar twice, often end up sending the getter message twice, or sending it the first time and (in the very same method) accessing the ivar directly (which is not a good idea either). For instance,

```
addComment: aString
    (self comments includes: aString) ifTrue: [^self].
    self comments add: aString

addComment: aString
    (self comments includes: aString) ifTrue: [^self].
    comments add: aString
```

In both cases the first line sends the message to make sure the ivar has been initialized. The second line has two options: it sends the message again (which is not necessary) or uses the ivar because the programmer knows the ivar was initialized above. This second option is error prone. For instance, there is some risk of making the following mistake:

```
addComment: aString
  (self acceptsDuplications not and: [self comments includes: aString])
    ifTrue: [^self].
  comments add: aString
```

When deciding about early versus lazy initialization I would also consider a third option. For instance one could inline the initialization in another method. Consider for instance

```
commentsDo: aBlock
  comments isNil ifTrue: [^self].
  comments do: [:c | aBlock value: c]
```

which doesn't need to initialize the ivar if not necessary.

Lazy initialization has also another side effect. For instance, suppose that the client says

```
 <receiver> comments isEmpty ifTrue: [^self nothingToDo].
```

where `<receiver>` is the object owning the `comments` ivar. This client code could have the side effect of initializing the ivar for no reason. Of course, clients shouldn't do this. Instead, the `<receiver>` should implement a `#hasComments` service, but these are things to take into account before populating the code with the LI technique.

Comment: An important further consideration is that Smalltalk has good code rewriting support, so if you needed to replace all those [xxx := OrderedCollection new] by a different collection type you can easily write a rewrite rule that applies that change to your whole code base (or a part).